# Where are OSM tile servers corresponding to its supported layers?

Tags: openstreetmap, layers, tiles, feature-layer, tile-server

On OpenStreetMap's main site (like [here](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=7/52.676/12.019)), there are 6 different layer options to choose from (like Standard, Transport Map, Cycle OSM, etc):
[image]

However, on [OSM's wiki on Tile Servers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles#Servers), not all of these layers are available! For example Transport layer is not available.

Doesn't OSM website itself use a tile server to fetch the tiles corresponding to its supported tiles? Where can I find the tile servers for all of these featured layers?

Comment: On the wiki, how many rows are you seeing in the "Base maps" table? I see 35, with the Thunderforest Transport map in 17th place. The latest revision was on [19 January 2021](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/w/index.php?title=Tiles&oldid=2094301), so it's not that someone added those base maps in the past few hours.

Comment: @Dondragmer Yes, but I only checked green columns. Didn't see the comment column that was suggesting it has a free offering but needs registration. Also its sample image didn't look like what that layer looks on the original openweathermap website for my selected city.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use your browser's web developer tools to see which URL is behind which layer. Most layers are served from a different tile server. Currently these are:

- Standard: tile.openstreetmap.org/
- CyclOSM: tile-cyclosm.openstreetmap.fr/cyclosm/
- Cycle Map: tile.thunderforest.com/cycle/
- Transport Map: tile.thunderforest.com/transport/
- ÖPNVKarte: tileserver.memomaps.de/tilegen/
- Humanitarian: openstreetmap.fr/hot/

The [Tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles#Servers) wiki page is just an example list of tile servers. It can be edited by anybody, so feel free to add the Transport layer to this list.